# How do I change the color of the span and i inside an anchor with CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to change the color of all elements inside of an anchor tag. These elements are i and span. However, I can't get my solution to work. Should I change the color one by one in CSS?

HTML and CSS

```css
.active-link {
  color: #2268ff;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav__item">
  <a href="#home" class="nav__link active-link">
    <i class="bx bx-home nav__icon"></i>
    <span class="nav__name">Home</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: actually not only span, but i will change color of i to

Comment: Actually its working, ive just tried it... not sure where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have shared should work. If this isn't working, I suspect some other CSS rules are overriding your CSS.
By default there shouldn't be a style attached to the `<span>` or `<i>` elements. They might get one from the browser (user agent stylesheet) or (like in your case) it should come from its parent (inherited from).
[Screenshot from browser developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIDTQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add the class name to the "li" tag

```css
.active-link {
  color: #2268ff;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav__item active-link">
  <a href="#home" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="bx bx-home nav__icon"></i>
    <span class="nav__name">Home</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.active-link > * {
    color: #2268ff;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav__item active-link">
  <a href="#home" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="bx bx-home nav__icon"></i>
    <span class="nav__name">Home</span>
  </a>
</li>
```